# Добавить доверенный сертификат

Tags: golang

Каким образом можно импортировать свой "self signed certificate" в хранилище корневых центров сертификации Windows?

`roots := x509.NewCertPool()`
`roots.AddCert(rootCert)`

Сертификат не добавляется в доверенные корневые центры сертификации (проверяю через MMC)

Comment: Как проявляется - _не работает_? Так и пишет: "я так не работаю"?

Comment: Не добавляется в доверенные корневые центры сертификации (проверяю через MMC)

Comment: Вместо коментариев дополняйте вопрос кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1184747/edit).